# Maintain SQL operator precedence when constructing Q objects in Django

Tags: sql, django, orm

I am trying to construct a complex query in Django by adding Q objects based on a list of user inputs:

```
from django.db.models import Q

q = Q()

expressions = [
    {'operator': 'or', 'field': 'f1', 'value': 1},
    {'operator': 'or', 'field': 'f2', 'value': 2},
    {'operator': 'and', 'field': 'f3', 'value': 3},
    {'operator': 'or', 'field': 'f4', 'value': 4},
]

for item in expressions:
    if item['operator'] == 'and':
       q.add(Q(**{item['field']:item['value']}), Q.AND )

    elif item['operator'] == 'or':
       q.add(Q(**{item['field']:item['value']}), Q.OR )
```

Based on this I am expecting to get a query with the following where condition:

```
f1 = 1 or f2 = 2 and f3 = 3 or f4 = 4
```

which, based on the default operator precedence will be executed as

```
f1 = 1 or (f2 = 2 and f3 = 3) or f4 = 4
```

however, I am getting the following query:

```
((f1 = 1 or f2 = 2) and f3 = 3) or f4 = 4
```

It looks like the Q() object forces the conditions to be evaluated in the order they were added.

Is there a way that I can keep the default SQL precedence? Basically I want to tell the ORM not to add parenthesis in my conditions.

Comment: Q() object is OK. It works the same way as evaluating a normal boolean expression with AND and OR. If you write a whole expression, it is parsed by Python with the correct precedence, but you use low-level operations step by step, it expects that you must execute them in the right order with creating appropriate temporary variables for subexpressions manually. Your code with `q.add(..., Q.operator)` is the same as `if item['operator'] == 'and': q = q & Q(...)` `elif item['operator'] == 'or': q = q | Q(...)` that is evaluated similarly to `boolean_variable |= boolean_value` immediately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<s>Seems that [you are not the only one with a **similar** problem](http://jehiah.cz/a/django-q-objects).</s> (edited due to @hynekcer 's comment)

A workaround would be to "parse" the incoming parameters into a list of `Q()` objects and create your query from that list:

```
from operator import or_
from django.db.models import Q

query_list = []

for item in expressions:
    if item['operator'] == 'and' and query_list:
        # query_list must have at least one item for this to work
        query_list[-1] = query_list[-1] & Q(**{item['field']:item['value']})
    elif item['operator'] == 'or':
        query_list.append(Q(**{item['field']:item['value']}))
    else:
        # If you find yourself here, something went wrong...
```

Now the `query_list` contains the individual queries as `Q()` or the `Q() AND Q()` relationships between them.
The list can be `reduce()`d with the `or_` operator to create the remaining `OR` relationships and used in a `filter()`, `get()` etc. query:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(reduce(or_, query_list))
```

---

**PS:** Although [Kevin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45194767/maintain-sql-operator-precedence-when-constructing-q-objects-in-django/45262469#45262469) is clever, [using `eval()` is considered a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice) and should be avoided.

Comment: The link to "jehiah.cz" above is not related because it is a workaround for a bug in Django that has been fixed many years ago (probably an early implementation of Q object). The problem in the question is not a problem in Q object, but an invalid order of evaluating the result.

Answer (score 5):

Since SQL precedence is the same as Python precedence when it comes to `AND`, `OR`, and `NOT`, you should be able to achieve what you want by letting Python parse the expression.

One quick-and-dirty way to do it would be to construct the expression as a string and let Python `eval()` it.

```
from functools import reduce

ops = ["&" if item["operator"] == "and" else "|" for item in expressions]
qs = [Q(**{item["field"]: item["value"]}) for item in expressions]

q_string = reduce(
    lambda acc, index: acc + " {op} qs[{index}]".format(op=ops[index], index=index),
    range(len(expressions)),
    "Q()"
) # equals "Q() | qs[0] | qs[1] & qs[2] | qs[3]"

q_expression = eval(q_string)
```

Python will parse this expression according to its own operator precedence, and the resulting SQL clause will match your expectations:

```
f1 = 1 or (f2 = 2 and f3 = 3) or f4 = 4
```

Of course, using `eval()` with user-supplied strings would be a major security risk, so here I'm constructing the `Q` objects separately (in the same way you did) and just referring to them in the eval string. So I don't think there are any additional security implications of using `eval()` here.

Comment: wow, very clever thinking outside of the box... love this workaround. I'll wait just to see if there is a way to make the ORM do this, otherwise i'll give it the bounty. Thanks